# At what point is "item" being inserted in this portion of code

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

Ok just to start I already know this is wrong i just can't figure out where "item" is being inserted so i can reverse the way this is happening:

```
void Enqueue(T item)
    {
    if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
       {

        Node *p = new Node; // creating a new node p
        Node *q = new Node;// creating a new node q
        front = p; // make p point directly to front
        p -> data = item; // set item equal to whatever is in p
        p->link = front; // um, pretty much saying the "front node" is next?
        num_items++;
       }
```

I guess my real problem is i lack a good understanding of pointers.

Note: NOT DONE WITH THIS EDIT DISREGARD

Comment: Why not draw a diagram?

Comment: @EdHeal that is actually waht i started doing lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im a little unsure of what you are asking here, but i will do my best to try and explain your code a little.

so your passing some data (an item obj) into your function

```
void Enqueue(T item)
```

checking the number of items (in a list i presume) is not at its max value

```
if(num_items != MAX_SIZE)
```

you then create a new object of type node

```
 Node *p = new Node; // creating a new node p
```

you then assign the data member (type T?) of the node to the item you passed in.

```
p -> data = item; // set item equal to whatever is in p
```

your then linking the last node (node on top of the stack of items) to this node (linking them together)

```
p->link = front; // um, pretty much saying the "front node" is next?
```

you then set the front variable to this node you just made (so you can link it to the next one or know where to start etc..)

```
front = p; // make p point directly to front?
```

and finally you increment the total num of items by 1

```
 num_items++;
```

like i said, im not to sure what you wanted to know, but i hope this helps you in some small way :)

to use the data you passed in (type T) you can use:

```
front->data->DATAMEMBER();
```

note: that will only work for the last link made, im sure you know what your doing there.

Comment: oh my god yes it did, so from my understanding now, i need a completely new node so that i can leave the front where it is and continue with a node i previously defined `rear`, so i can keep adding `item` after front. if that makes any sense to you

Comment: Still a little confused on what your after, then again its 5:35am here and its been a long night.

your code seems to be a basic link list. - a stack of objects linked together, like a chain.

from what i can tell you want to add more items to this list?

to do that all you need to do is call Enqueue as many times as you want links.

for example if you have 3 items of type T called a, b & c. to add them to this link list all you would need to do is call Enqueue and pass in the item objects of type T
Enqueue(a);
Enqueue(b);
Enqueue(c);

Comment: Also, if you have a rear variable of type node (like your front var) you'd probably want to leave that set to the 1st item's node you create.

a quick dirty way of accessing through nodes would be

nodeobj->link->link->data->MEMBEROFITEM();

What would be the 3rd link c in my examples case

Comment: oops sorry about that last comment, i understand now thank you.

Comment: ah right, so your after it to basically reverse the way the data is stored (atm it could be 5,4,3,2,1) but you want it to be like (1,2,3,4,5)?

in that case you have a few options, you can add the data in the correct order, traverse the data in reverse, (instead of front->blablabla it would be rear->blablabla) or you can just go through your list and sort it.

but in all honesty id just use a std::vector, it will save you alot of time.

Comment: oh we haven't come to vector's yet in my class but i'll definitely do some research on those

Comment: Not a problem, if your question is answered don't forget to mark the correct answer :)
Glad i could be of some assistance.

Comment: - a vector or a std::list is basically a link list with a set of members you can call to make your life much, much easier.

eg,

Comment: std::vector<T> items;

T itemobj = new T();

items.push_back(itemobj);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47572/discussion-between-breon-thibodeaux-and-makka)